# Vertical line at 99% point of my data in R (imitating confidence interval)

Tags: r, plot

I have very simple question, i need to make vertical line at 99% of my data which sound pretty simple. After research I found out that most convenient (what i thought) is to use the `quantile` function. To make it simpler I use here training data with 90% instead of 99%:

```
conf_c = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
hist(conf_c)
abline(v=quantile(conf_c,0.9), col="red")
quantile(conf_c, 0.9)
```

but this method gives me number of **9.1**, and i was going to exact **9** (which is 90%). Is there any simple workaround?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Use `quantile(conf_c, 0.9, type = 1)`. See `types` subsection of `?quantile`.

Comment: Ok that works, thank you. Somehow I did not get this from ?quantile description.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `round` function as below:

```
## Your code    
conf_c <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
hist(conf_c)
abline(v=quantile(conf_c,0.9), col="red")

## Suggestion & output:
cutoff <- quantile(conf_c,0.9)
abline(v=round(cutoff), col="blue")
legend("topleft", legend=c("`quantile`", "`round`"), col=c("red", "blue"), lty=1)
```

[image]
Hopefully this is a solution that you wanted.